# Select dynamic HTML Element via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, jquery-file-upload

I am building an ASP.NET MVC application and I am using the [jQuery Blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin on a PartialView that is added dynamically to the page.

According to the Docs of the plugin I need to do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But this of course will not work in my case, because my PartialView does not exist on the page at first.

So my question is, how can I grab the dynamically added file input, and initialize `.fileupload` on it. I have tried the following as suggested by Archer, but it isn't working:

```
$(function () {
    $('#campaign-form-wrap').on("change", "#fileUpload", function () {
        $('#fileUpload').fileupload({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/ZenosIntranet/Campaign/ConvertExcelToVehicleDriverSummariesJson",
            limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
            sequentialUploads: true,
            maxChunkSize: 10000,
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.results, function() {
                    alert("boo");
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I also ensured I have the correct ordering of the scripts as suggested on answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079670/unable-to-get-blueimp-jquery-fileupload-plugin-to-work). But still no go. I am getting the following error now:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload'

**UPDATE:** I think the syntax above is incorrect, because even when I do `this.siblings()` in Chrome's console, I get the error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'siblings'

Which suggests to me that the code thinks my this object has a method called siblings or fileupload - but do they? I know in the case of fileupload I am wanting to attach it to that control.

Comment: I would change `submit` to `change` on the file upload function. `submit` *does* feel kinda out of place.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't `change` fire on me simply clicking the button to upload the file too?

Comment: Also, about the `not defined` issue - could you not define the function like `function file_upload() { fileupload({ ....`, and then call the function with: `$('#campaign-form-wrap').on("change", "#fileUpload", file_upload);`?

Comment: No, `change` would fire the function when the value in the field change (if you add/change the file placed there).

Comment: Thanks, tried what you suggested, I get same error again. fileupload not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler is actually trying to run the function immediately.  You need to wrap it in an anonymous function so it is only called when the event occurs...

```
$(function () {
    $('#campaign-form-wrap').on("submit", "#fileUpload", function() {
        $(this).fileupload({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/ZenosIntranet/Campaign/ConvertExcelToVehicleDriverSummariesJson",
            limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
            sequentialUploads: true,
            maxChunkSize: 10000,
            done: function(e, data) {
                $.each(data.results, function() {
                    alert("boo");
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks good, but still getting the same error :( I put an `alert()` before the `.fileupload()` and that fired fine, so I know the function is attempting to run, but I get the same fileupload undefined error :(

Comment: I'll have a look at the blueimp documentation and see if I can find something.

Comment: It's actually sounding like a possible conflict issue.  The above change is still required, as you were previously running the function immediately, but have a look here and see if this helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079670/unable-to-get-blueimp-jquery-fileupload-plugin-to-work

Comment: Updated Q. I ensured the order was correct too, but still error as detailed in updated Q. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the rendered html (from a "view source") for the form?  Something's obviously not right somewhere.

Comment: Rendered HTML *after* dynamic content loaded can be [found here](http://pastebin.com/jisZJP6L).

Comment: I've just confirmed the casings, they all look correct! even in the link I gave! Can you please confirm!?

Comment: Yes, the cases are the same in the code you gave me, but if you've copied and pasted the code I gave above then it wouldn't work.  Did you fix the case difference with that?

Comment: Ah I see. Yes my casing is correct, but still same error :( Is there a way I can confirm the order of scripts being loaded?

Comment: What happens if you open the console and type `$("#fileUpload").fileupload();`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47342/discussion-between-ciwan-and-archer)

Comment: Sorry mate - I'm going off for the day now.  All I would recommend is moving your script to after the script includes, just to be 100% sure about the order.  Other than that it looks fine to me so I'm a bit lost.  I hope you get somewhere with it - good luck :)

Comment: I tried what you suggested about `$("#fileUpload").fileupload();` and got the error: `TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'fileupload'`

Comment: Q. Updated with some further console play.

Answer (score 0):

So after a long discussion with Archer and many others, we figured the problem out.

The input form was coming through a PartialView.cshtml in my ASP.NET MVC application. Even though I had my plugin initialization code wrapped around a jQuery's `.on()` function, the plugin was still attempting to initialize things on initial page load.

I'm not sure why that is, my guess is that the plugin was designed that way!

So what I did was, I moved all script files related to the plugin from MVC's `_Layout.cshtml` and put them inside my `_PartialView.cshtml`.

This forced the plugin scripts to run as soon as the partial appeared on the page, and the plugin then worked fine.

**NOTE:** You still need to ensure that the ordering of the script files is correct.

- jQuery
- Widget UI
- iFrame Transport
- FileUpload

I hope this helps.